# clustering co-occuring words around one specific keyword

Tags: networking, cluster-analysis, keyword, cpu-word

I want to detect which words co-occur around one particular topic I am interested - e.g., let's say my interest topic is "economic policy" and I have 100 documents as data. I want to extract co-occuring words around "economic policy" from the 100 documents. If I can also see the changes of co-occuring words over time, that would be perfect. What methods should I look for? I had keyword clustering or keyword network over time in mind, but for those methods one cannot set one specific word to extract co-occuring words with that one word. Can you suggest something?? Thank you!

I had keyword clustering or keyword network over time in mind, but for those methods one cannot set one specific word to extract co-occuring words with that one word.